# Sort and paginate custom post taxonomies alphabetically

Tags: custom-taxonomy, theme-development, themes, sort

I need to sort and paginate custom taxonomy post types. i have a page where i have next and previous link. on clicking next and previous link next or previous brand(custom taxonomy) should load. I have achieved this so far

```
 $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'brand' );
if($terms) {
  $BrandId=$terms[0]->term_id;
  $nextBrandId=$BrandId+1;
  $prevBranId=$BrandId-1;
  $next=get_term_by('id', $nextBrandId, 'brand' );
  $prev=get_term_by('id', $prevBranId, 'brand' );

  //echo '<pre>';
   echo $next->slug;
    echo $prev->slug;
   // echo '</pre>';
 }
```

I am getting next and previous brand slug by id and they are showing randomly (if i talk in alphabetic order).

Please tell me how can i show next and previous link that are sorted by alphateicallhy.

For eg
I have following brands

```
Versace, Valentino, Armani, Rado, CK, Tissot
```

If currently i am at Tissot and click next then i should go to Valentino.
If i am at Tissot and click prev then i should go to Rado.

Comment: You either need to use `usort` or `wp_get_post_terms` to sort your post terms by name

Comment: can you please share some example.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in comments, you can either use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort the returned array of terms, or you can just use [`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) which is already sorted by default by name in ascending order

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'brand' );
var_dump( $terms );
```

### EDIT

Here is an example with `usort()` and `get_the_terms()`

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'brand' );
usort( $terms, function ( $a, $b )
{

    return strcasecmp( $a->name, $b->name );

});
```

Comment: see i know that i need to use usort() but i am not understanding and getting the point that how should i use this. Because i am in a situation. where i have current Active brand id name and details and want to move to the very next or previous brand in alphabetic orders. I just need some code example.

Comment: You don't have to use `usort()`, you can use `wp_get_post_terms()` which is already sorted by name. It does the same exact thing as `get_the_terms`. I will update my answer to include `usort()`

Comment: see i have following scenario http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/186364/aac00c1eec8f4dccd6bea4c6ab9cda34 i am having listing of products inside custom taxonomy in a page and want to move to next taxonomy page where taxonomy products will be displayed. i cannot use wp_get_post_terms and if i can then how will i get the slug of next or previous brand.

Comment: See my update. Hope that is what you are looking for

Comment: I think usort() with strcasecmp() would be a bad idea, since strcasecmp() is not utf8 save as far as I know. See for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655092/comparing-utf-8-string

Comment: @websupporter As I have stated, it is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the same thing to achieve this but finally i found a better solution [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/alphabetic-pagination/). It works with regular taxonomies (categories) and also work with custom taxonomies. You should check its code inside or can use it as it is if the requirements are the same.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Two suggestions: If the external link goes down or changes, then we might not be any wiser regarding the solution, so please add the relevant information into the answer. If you're promoting your own plugin, it would be nice to know that too. Thanks.

Comment: I could paste that code snippet here but that will not make any sense except that a query. WordPress custom post taxonomies are involved and a few hooks are used in that, it would be a lengthy answer in that way and still will not help as compare to a working/ready code.